# How to Send camelCase Json to C# Web Api to Match Pascal Properties WithOut Error

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, camelcasing, pascalcasing

Currently I'm using this JsonFormatter to send camel-cased data to the client

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

---

**WebApiConfig**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace AlumCloud
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            ((Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver)config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;


            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

Eveything works perfectly, my data is received on the client as expected perfectly.

Now, it is time to start sending data to the server and I am using the

```
C# Web Api in the .NET platform.
```

Here is the POST function I am attempting to post camel Cased JSON data to with the one C# object, I've removed most of the code for clarity.

**WebApi Controller**

```
namespace AlumCloud.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HorizontalController : AlumCloudWebApiBaseController
    {
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(Horizontal h)
        {
            string update = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["a"];
            int ownerID = 0; ;
            HttpResponseMessage res = null;
            InsertHorizontalHelper insertRes = null;

            if (!int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"], out ownerID))
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Provide the id of the horizontal owner");
            };

            if (h.CompID < 1)
            {
                if (h.Sitelines.TopCompID > 0)
                {
                    h.CompID = h.Sitelines.TopCompID;
                };
            }
            switch (update)
            {
```

---

Here is the way the Properties of the Horizontal object look like, they are Pascal Cased

**C# Customer Object I want to map properties from JSON to C#**

```
namespace CADDL.DataTransfer.Tables
{

    [XmlType(Namespace = "urn:DataObjects")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:DataObjects")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Horizontal : ColumnInfo, IHorizontal
    {


        [ColumnAttributes("ID", false, "int")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [ColumnAttributes("Position", false, "byte")]
        public byte Position { get; set; }
        [ColumnAttributes("Name", false, "string")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ColumnAttributes("IsFiller", false, "bool")]
        public bool IsFiller { get; set; }
        [ColumnAttributes("HorizontalNote", false, "string")]
        public string HorizontalNote { get; set; }
        [ColumnAttributes("SizeID", false, "int")]
        public int SizeID { get; set; }
        [ColumnAttributes("WidthInches", false, "decimal")]
        public decimal WidthInches { get; set; }
        [ColumnAttributes("HeightInches", false, "decimal")]
```

---

**My Error**

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","exceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","stackTrace":"   at AlumCloud.Controllers.HorizontalController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\\Users\\Erik Little\\Documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\AlumCloud\\AlumCloud\\Controllers\\CAD\\HorizontalController.cs:line 28\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

**My questions to the group are.**

1. Why is my Horizontal C# object always null is it because the JSON is Camel cased and the properties it is matching to is Pascal Cased?
2. Does the Properties mapper from the JSON to the C# object have to be the same case in order for the value to be set?
3. What is a global way to fix this issue so that I do not have to add attributes are setting in every new Web Api controller?

**Just for clarity the attributes you see on each property are for my data layer, for when requesting data, they're not used in this instance**

Comment: Why do you set the foramtter to use camelCase if your client is a .Net client and expects a Pascal case?

Comment: I was confused about this area, the client expects camel case and the source expects Pascal case, remember, i was confused, come to find out it was an typeO error in my class. the sending the camelCase to the client is mandatory for JavaScript. It has been about a year since I've used these technologies so I am caught up now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way the objects are being received by the client and being processed on the server require two different objects to make life easier, so I've created a folder called client request and so there is no name clashes I've named the Horizontal class from the client size HorizontalRequest but with only the properties needed to satisfy the clients.

The class objects on the server are somewhat larger than what is needed to receive a JSON request so for when clients send data where server objects are 20 x larger than what is needed I'll just create classes like the HorizontalRequest, bare bone, no attributes, just properties.